# Linear Model Output - which treatments are different from each other?

Tags: r, regression

How do you determine which supplements are not different from each other (within the listed rows)?

```
model <- lm(gain~diet+supplement)

                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          26.1230     0.4408  59.258  < 2e-16 ***
dietoats             -3.0928     0.4408  -7.016 1.38e-08 ***
dietwheat            -5.9903     0.4408 -13.589  < 2e-16 ***
supplementcontrol    -2.6967     0.5090  -5.298 4.03e-06 ***
supplementsupergain  -3.3815     0.5090  -6.643 4.72e-08 ***
supplementsupersupp  -0.7274     0.5090  -1.429     0.16    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.247 on 42 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8531,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8356 
F-statistic: 48.76 on 5 and 42 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: The way you've set things up, you're only testing relative to whatever your reference level is.

Comment: This is not the (best) way to investigate which supplements are (not) different from each other. This is a way to investigate which supplements are (not) different from your baseline supplement (i.e. the one missing from your output) given that you control for variable `diet`.

Answer (score 1):

To compare treatments you can use a pairwise comparison test, for example the Tukey HSD test:

```
TukeyHSD(aov(model), 'diet')
```